# How do I get a Compile error from NVIDIA CG?

Tags: compiler-errors, nvidia, cg

How do I get detailed errors from a cg compile?

At the moment my code is something like:

```
prog = cgCreateProgramFromFile(
    context,
    CG_SOURCE,
    filename,
    proifile,
    null,null);
std::cout << cgGetErrorString(cgGetError());
```

But all I get is "The compile returned an error."

Is there any way to get a more involved error message, like glGetShaderiv with GL_COMPILE_STATUS for opengl shaders?

Can't find anything in the reference but is seems like a fairly basic requirement.

I am running cgc on the shaders first with no code generation to check for errors but that doesn't catch everything.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the case of a compile error, you must use cgGetLastListing(CGcontext) instead of cgGetError(void).

From the Cg documentation for cgGetLastListing(CGcontext):

> Each Cg context maintains a
>   NULL-terminated string containing
>   warning and error messages generated
>   by the Cg compiler, state managers and
>   the like. cgGetLastListing allows
>   applications and custom state managers
>   to query the listing text.
>
> cgGetLastListing returns the currrent
>   listing string for the given
>   CGcontext. When a Cg runtime error
>   occurs, applications can use the
>   listing text from the appropriate
>   context to provide the user with
>   detailed information about the error.

Comment: Thanks, must have turned over two html pages at once, its not exactly intuitively named.